# How do I write an algorithm with two columns to its right?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, algorithms

I know about verbatim which I use to write code, but how in the world can I get a table like this?

[image: this]

The reason why I do not just write it in verbatim is that I want to apply effects like `\texttt` and `$..$`.

Comment: You  can  use `algorithm2e` package

Comment: @user94293 How would you do the horizontal alignment with `algorithm2e`?